# Fill existing SQLite database with data from JSON (or other easily-readable text format) in C#

Tags: c#, json, database, sqlite

My database is divided into two parts: language-independent part and localizable part (containing Unicode text strings). For our translation staff it's much more easier to work not with some DB viewing tool but with some text format like JSON (via some tool of course). So I'm looking for a best way to load JSON data into my SQLite database. For now I use the foolowing approach (assume that I already have empty SQLite database):

1. I deserealise JSON data into C# classes (via Newtonsoft.JSON.dll).
2. For each of them I **manually** create INSERT command with paremeters (via System.Data.SQLite.dll) and then fill that parameters with class fields' values
3. I execute that command.

Is that correct (easiest, reliable) aproach to fill SQLite database with JSON data? Maybe I've missed some useful API?

Any other easily-readable text format (with Unicode support!) which is better to work with in term of C# and SQLite is welcomed.

Comment: CSV is a lot easier, in fact SQLite can import CSV files directly. It can even *read* CSV files as if they were SQLite databases

Answer (score 1):

Try Sqlite.NET, a basic Sqlite client and ORM: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

From their wiki:

> Once you have defined your entity, you can automatically generate
>   tables in your database by calling CreateTable:
>
> ```
> var db = new SQLiteConnection("foofoo");
> db.CreateTable<Stock>();
> db.CreateTable<Valuation>();
> ```
>
> You can insert rows in the database using Insert. If the table
>   contains an auto-incremented primary key, then the value for that key
>   will be available to you after the insert:
>
> ```
> public static void AddStock(SQLiteConnection db, string symbol) {
>     var s = db.Insert(new Stock() {
>         Symbol = symbol
>     });
>     Console.WriteLine("{0} == {1}", s.Symbol, s.Id);
> }
> ```
>
> Similar methods exist for Update and Delete.

You would get something like this:

```
AddStock(string jsonString){
    var stock = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stock>(jsonString);
    db.Insert(stock);
}
```

Comment: Thx. I'm already using good SQLite clien and ORM (from Devart) as well. Tooling in not the core of my question. I'm asking am I missing some JSON aouto-load API of better Unicode tex format

Comment: Ah I see. I was mainly responding to step 2 in your approach. The rest seems fine to me, what would you like to improve?

Comment: Some kind of "magic function" FillAQLiteDBWithData(SQLiteDBConnection, JSONString) maybe

Comment: I don't know of any such magic :) But it seems to me that deserializing into objects, and storing those objects using an ORM, without manually creating insert statements, is already pretty concise and readable. Don't you think?

Comment: I added an example of, is that what you were looking for, or do you want to actually save the JSON string into the db?

Comment: Thx, I will try it. If `db.Insert(stock)` will work out-of-the-box (in case that Stock table with appropriate fields already exists in database) - that's what I need.